# Pairs insertion/retrieval in/from field

Tags: java, json, mongodb, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to insert pairs in a mongoDB Document. This how i am doing it so far:

```
private static MongoCollection<Document> getCollectionn(String link, String coll){
     ...
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        MongoCollection<Document> fb_users;
        fb_users = getCollectionn("mongodb://...", "fb_users2");
        Document myDoc;
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        query.put("fbid", "1");
        myDoc = fb_users.find(query).first();
        int postId=5;
        int rating=3;                  
        fb_users.updateOne(myDoc,
           new Document("$push", new Document("ratings",  java.util.Arrays.asList(rating, postId))));

        Object a = myDoc.get("ratings");
        ArrayList<Document> b = (ArrayList<Document>) a;
        System.out.println(b.get(0);//prints [3, 5]
}
```

This is how the array document is inserted in the collection after two runs:
(the document already exists)

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56f173b5e4b04eaac6531030"
    },
    "fbid": "1",
    "ratings": [
        [
            3,
            5
        ],
        [
            3,
            5
        ]
    ]
}
```

In println i get the result [3, 5]

My question is this:

How can i recieve the numder 3 and the number 5 seperatly? Should i insert the documents with another way? Iam using mongo java driver 3.2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the solution. Here it is:

```
    Document myDoc;   
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("fbid", "1");
    myDoc = fb_users.find(query).first();
    int postId=5;
    int rating=3;
    Document listItem = new Document("ratings", new   Document(String.valueOf(rating), String.valueOf(postId)));
    Document updateQuery = new Document("$push", listItem);
    fb_users.updateOne(myDoc, updateQuery);
    MongoCursor<Document> curs = fb_users.find(query).iterator();
    ArrayList<Document> list  = (ArrayList<Document>) myDoc.get("ratings");
    Iterator<Document> iterateList = list  .iterator();
    while(iterateList .hasNext()){
        Document pair = iterateList .next();
        for(String element : pair.keySet()){
            System.out.println(element + " " + pair.get(element));
        }
    }
```

and the json format is and should be like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56f173b5e4b04eaac6531030"
    },
    "fbid": "1",
    "ratings": [
        {
            "3": "5"
        },
        {
            "3": "5"
        }
    ]
}
```